# Can use jquery animate to specific height and width while keeping the top and left as constant?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

```
$(div).animate({
    height:"40px",
    width:"40px",
    top:"0px",
    left:"0px"
}); // In this case i want the top and left to be set at 0px.
```

but the div is shrinking to a different position

My div is currently in position of top : 50px and left:50 px with height 100px and width 100 px.I want to move it top 0px and left 0px and make its  height 40px and width 40px

Comment: hello Dharini, can you please add some your HTML code or jsfiddle link, so I can get idea what you need. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first be sure you set `left:"0px"` like this, with `""`

second. it should work. see below in snippet :

maybe you have some other code that is interfering

```js
$("div").animate({ height:"40px", width:"40px", top:"0px", left:'0px' });
```

```css
div {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

</div>
```